# mkfs.ext4 command not found in Debian (Jessie)

Tags: debian, ext4, mkfs

I have just installed Debian 8.4 (Jessie, MATE desktop). For some reason the following command is not recognized:

```
mkfs.ext4 -L hdd_misha /dev/sdb1
```

The error I get:

```
bash: mkfs.ext4: command not found
```

I have googled and I actually can't seen to find Debian-specific instructions on how to create an ext4 filesystem. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: do you have `/sbin` in your path?  are you running this as a normal user or as root?  unless you've added it yourself (e.g. in `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` etc), root has `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` in $PATH, but normal users don't by default.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do you have `/sbin` in your path?

Most likely you are trying to run `mkfs.ext4` as a normal user.

Unless you've added it yourself (e.g. in `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` etc), root has `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` in `$PATH`, but normal users don't by default.

Try running it from a root shell (e.g. after `sudo -i`) or as:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -L hdd_misha /dev/sdb1
```

BTW, normal users usually don't have the necessary permissions to use `mkfs`to format a partition (although they can format a disk-image file that they own - e.g. for use with `FUSE` or in a VM with, say, VirtualBox).

Formatting a partition requires root privs unless someone has seriously messed up the block device permissions in `/dev`.

Answer (score 1):

On some very slimmed down distributions (e.g. Ubuntu Server) it's possible that you don't have `mkfs` installed. In which case, you can install it with:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install dosfstools
```

You may also want `ntfsprogs` for `mkfs.ntfs`.

(The package name should be the same in other distros e.g `pacman -S dosfstools`)

Answer (score 1):

On some systems it is possible that you have mkfs installed and /sbin in your path, but ext2, ext3 and ext4 utilities are not installed.
You can install them with e2fsprogs:

```
sudo apt install e2fsprogs
```

Comment: One more solution. I was trying to format a USB in the Disks utility but could not choose the format I wanted. I had all of the above packages, so I ran a search for apt packages with "exfat" in the name. Found and installed exfatprogs, now I can format to exFAT.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar issue on Ubuntu server 20.04.4 LTS arm. The solution was to install exfat-utils.

Here was my error message.

```
$ sudo mkfs.exfat /dev/sdb1
sudo: mkfs.exfat: command not found
```

I attempted to run the command as the root user after issuing

```
$ sudo -i
```

This time it prompted me to install exfat-utils

```
root@ubuntu:~# mkfs.exfat /dev/sdb1
Command 'mkfs.exfat' not found, but can be installed with:
apt install exfat-utils
```

After this I moved back to normal user and the format command was successful.

```
$ sudo mkfs.exfat -n toshiba_silver /dev/sdb1
mkexfatfs 1.3.0
Creating... done.
Flushing... done.
File system created successfully.
```